# Convergence of the square of a positive sequence to the square of a positive function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $\;f_n,f\in L^2(\mathbb R;\mathbb R^m)\;$ and assume $\;{\vert \vert f_n \vert \vert}^2_{L^2} \to {\vert \vert f \vert \vert}^2_{L^2}\;$.

Is it true that $\;{\vert \vert f_n \vert \vert}_{L^2} \to {\vert \vert f \vert \vert}_{L^2}\;$ and why?

I thought that since $\;{\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert}_{L^2}\;$ is a positive function then it must be true. However, this "explanation" doesn't convince me...

I believe it's something absolutely obvious I 'm missing here, but I've been stuck. Any help would be valuable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $0 \le x_n,x \in \mathbb{R}, x_n^2 \to x^2$, then $x_n \to x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $u\rightarrow u^{1/2}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, so $(\|u_{n}\|_{L^{2}}^{2})^{1/2}\rightarrow(\|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2})^{1/2}$.

Comment: This is what I needed! Thanks a lot!